# Multiple scene nodes in PropertySheet Editor JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx, propertysheet

I want to add checkbox and textfield to one property of `PropertySheet` (`ControlsFX` library). Is it possible or no? So, i just need to add some GUI elements together to one `PropertyEditor`, for example checkbox + button, checkbox + label, checkbox + textfield and etc. Is it possible to override `PropertyEditor` to do it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes of cource it is possible !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. I tried to add checkbox + combobox to HBox. Code below, it works.

```
    public static final <T> PropertyEditor<?> createCheckBoxLinkEditor(PropertySheet.Item property,
        final Collection<T> choices) {
    ComboBox<T> comboBox = new ComboBox<T>();
    comboBox.setCellFactory((ListView<T> p) -> new ListCell<T>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
            } else if (item instanceof Class) {
                setText(((Class) item).getSimpleName());
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    hbox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
    hbox.getChildren().add(comboBox);
    //hbox.getA
    //comboBox.setConverter(value);
    return new AbstractPropertyEditor<T, HBox>(property, hbox) {

        {
            comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(choices));
            //new AutoCompleteComboBoxListener(comboBox);
            new SelectKeyComboBoxListener(comboBox);
        }

        @Override
        protected ObservableValue<T> getObservableValue() {
            return comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(T value) {
            comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also wrap multiples nodes inside a single parent .[See Here[image: ][1]]